# Resolving type with PerRequestLifetimeManager without HTTP request

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest, unity-container, hangfire

I have a MVC application that uses IoC with Unity and I have a `DbContext` implementation defined using the `PerRequestLifetimeManager`. This object is injected to controllers through Unit of Work implementation.

```
container.RegisterType<DBContext, MyContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

Everything is working fine so far and the app has a decent number of models and controllers. Now what I was trying to do recently is add some automated tasks for this application and for this purpose I wanted to use [HangFire](http://hangfire.io).

I've set up this library in my project and created a simple task in which I want to invoke an action that requires a `DBContext`.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => MyTask(), Cron.Daily);
```

and `MyTask()` is defined as follows

```
public void MyTask()
{
    var taskManager = container.Resolve<ITaskManager>();
    taskManager.DoSomething();
}
```

Task manager requires an instance of DBContext (through Unit of Work object)

```
public class TaskManager : ITaskManager
{
    public TaskManager(IUnitOfWork uow) {
        ...
    }
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public class UnitOfWork(DBContext context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now the problem I have is whenever the task runs I get the exception saying `PerRequestLifetimeManager can only be used in the context of an HTTP request`.

Is there a way I could inject this object without HTTP request or how can I change my Unity configuration to also support my HangFire tasks?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have moved away from using `PerRequestLifetimeManager` for this very issue.  I have now started using `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` with [container hierarchies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507462.aspx) instead and then you need to set up your app to create a new child container per intended scope (such as a request or a job) and dispose that child container when that scope is complete.

There are some libraries that hook into MVC and WebAPI to create a new child container per request.  A quick search found this one for MVC: [Unity.Mvc5](https://github.com/devtrends/Unity.Mvc5) and the official [Unity.AspNet.WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.AspNet.WebApi/) NuGet package includes a `UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver`.

To get this to work with your task app, you will have to roll your own method to create a child container to control your scope, but that is pretty easy.  Just call `IUnityContainer childContainer = container.CreateChildContainer()`, resolve your instances using the child container and do your work and then at the end of your scope call `childContainer.Dispose()`.