# Validating MVC controller DI registration with Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to add a test that validates that all the MVC controllers in my project can resolve successfully.
I get them with

```
MvcControlleractionlist = asm.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof (System.Web.Mvc.Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type));
```

In the test I try to resolve them with:

```
foreach (var mvcController in MvcControlleractionlist)
{
    Container.Resolve(mvcController);
}
```

The error I get is this:

InnerException = {"The PerRequestLifetimeManager can only be used in the context of an HTTP request. Possible causes for this error are using the lifetime manager on a non-ASP.NET application, or using it in a thread that is not associated with the appropriate synchronizati...

I assume MVC in the background registers all the controllers with the PerRequestLifetimeManager. How can I make MVC think the test is running within an HTTP request?

Comment: Possible related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192431/perrequestlifetimemanager-can-only-be-used-in-the-context-of-an-http-request

Comment: I'd flip this test around.  I would run your registration code then verify that the types registered in the container match the types in the assembly.  I wouldn't actually try to resolve all the types.

Comment: also add your registration code for the container.

Comment: Fran thanks, I can do the validation of the services that are registered, but if a new service is created and added to the controller, but not to container the application will fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not resolving the controller, but iterating through the constructor's dependecies.

```
    protected virtual List<TypeStruct> GetTypesToResolveFromClassType(Type classType)
    {
        var typeToResolves = new List<TypeStruct>();

        var constructors = classType.GetConstructors();
        foreach (ConstructorInfo constructorInfo in constructors)
        {
            var parameterInfos = constructorInfo.GetParameters();
            foreach (ParameterInfo parameterInfo in parameterInfos.Where(t => t.ParameterType.IsInterface || t.ParameterType.IsAbstract))
            {
                DependencyAttribute dependencyAttribute = (DependencyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(parameterInfo, typeof(DependencyAttribute));
                var type = parameterInfo.ParameterType;
                typeToResolves.Add(new TypeStruct { type = type, DependencyName = dependencyAttribute?.Name });
            }
        }

        return typeToResolves;
    }
```