# Unity Container With Repository and UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I have an ASP.NET WEB API project that using the repository and unit of work patterns along with UnityContainer. I registered all my repositories and unit of work classes with PerRequestLifeTimeManager and everything is working great. Every client request to server work in a single transaction separated from other client requests. After the request is returned to the client, the DbContext is disposed.

My problem begins when I need to to perform heavy actions after I return a response to the client. The DbContext is disposed and I can't request the Unity Container for a new instance (Since no HttpContext exist ).

I read this post [PerRequestLifetimeManager can only be used in the context of an HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192431/perrequestlifetimemanager-can-only-be-used-in-the-context-of-an-http-request)
And tried to implement 2 different UnityContainer

1. WebContainer - Register all classes using PerRequestLifeTimeManager
2. CorContainer - Register all classes using PerResolveLifetimeManager

I thought I solved the problem but I noticed that each repository I request from the CoreContainer using a different DbContext. Also the UnitOfWork has a different DbContext. This off course causing many error in my code.

This is the code I'm using to register my entities in UnityContainer. I have 2 Databases so some of the repository using the DbContext of the first database, and the other using the second DbContext. My UnitOfWork using both DbContexts

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> perRequestContainer =
      new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
      {
          var container = new UnityContainer();
          RegisterCommonTypes<PerRequestLifetimeManager>(container);
          return container;
      });

    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> perResolveContainer =
      new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
      {
          var container = new UnityContainer();
          RegisterCommonTypes<PerResolveLifetimeManager>(container);
          //CNSDeployerService can 
          container.RegisterType<ICNSDeployerService, CNSDeployerService>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
          return container;
      });


    public static IUnityContainer WebContainer => perRequestContainer.Value;
    public static IUnityContainer CoreContainer => perResolveContainer.Value;
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Please notice this configuration exist only inside the scope of a single request 
    /// See UnityWebApiActivator
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container"></param>
    public static void RegisterCommonTypes<T>(IUnityContainer container) where T: LifetimeManager
    {
        container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<capNsubContext, capNsubContext>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());

        container.RegisterType<IDataContextAsync, capNsubContext>("capNsubContext", Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<IDataContextAsync, LinetServerContext>("linnetDataContext", Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<IRepository<Entity>, Repository<Entity>>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<VideoTargetLanguage>, Repository<VideoTargetLanguage>>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        //Unity understand array by defaults so we just need to map it to IEnumerable
        container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<IDataContextAsync>, IDataContextAsync[]>();
        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());

        container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<AccountController>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());

        container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<IOrderService, OrderService>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<IFFMpegService, FFMpegService>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<IVideoService, VideoService>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<IOrderItemService, OrderItemService>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<ILanguageService, LanguageService>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());

        container.RegisterType<ICNSCaptionsService, CNSCaptionsService>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<ICNSTranslationsService, CNSTranslationsService>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<ICNSCapMoviesService, CNSMovieService>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<HttpClient, HttpClient>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        container.RegisterType<SimpleRefreshTokenProvider, SimpleRefreshTokenProvider>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());

        var capNsubEntityTypes = GetEntityFrameworkEntityTypesByContext<capNsubContext>();
        var linnetEntityTypes = GetEntityFrameworkEntityTypesByContext<LinetServerContext>();
        RegisterEntitiesRepostiories<T>(container, capNsubEntityTypes, "capNsubContext");
        RegisterEntitiesRepostiories<T>(container, linnetEntityTypes, "linnetDataContext");
    }

    private static void RegisterEntitiesRepostiories<T>(IUnityContainer container, IEnumerable<Type> entities, string contextName)
        where T:LifetimeManager
    {
        var iGenericRepositoryTypes = new[] { typeof(IRepositoryAsync<>), typeof(IRepository<>) };
        foreach (var iGenericRepositoryType in iGenericRepositoryTypes)
        {
            foreach (var entityType in entities)
            {
                var iSpecificRepositoryType = iGenericRepositoryType.MakeGenericType(entityType);
                var genericRepositoryType = typeof(Repository<>);
                var specificRepositoryType = genericRepositoryType.MakeGenericType(entityType);

                container.RegisterType(iSpecificRepositoryType, Activator.CreateInstance<T>(), new InjectionFactory(c =>
                {
                    return Activator.CreateInstance(specificRepositoryType, c.Resolve<IDataContextAsync>(contextName), c.Resolve<IUnitOfWorkAsync>());
                }));
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetEntityFrameworkEntityTypesByContext<T>() where T : DataContext
    {
        var capNsubContextType = typeof(T);
        var capNsubDataAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(capNsubContextType);
        var ef6EntityType = typeof(Repository.Pattern.Ef6.Entity);

        return capNsubDataAssembly.GetTypes()
                  .Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, capNsubContextType.Namespace, StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
                    t.IsSubclassOf(ef6EntityType));

    }
}


[System.Web.Http.Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
[System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/job")]
public class JobController : BaseApiController { 


    [System.Web.Http.Route("Create", Name = "Create")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Create(JobBindingModel createJobModal)
    {
        //We have to use the CoreContainer since cnsDeployer scope runs outside of the request
        var cnsDeployer = UnityConfig.CoreContainer.Resolve<ICNSDeployerService>();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        try
        {
            //This runs in the backround after we return the response to client
            cnsDeployer.Deploy(createJobModal.ItemIds);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            return InternalServerError(err);
        }

    }
}

 public class CNSDeployerService : ICNSDeployerService
{
    private readonly IOrderItemService orderItemService;
    private readonly ICNSCapMoviesService cnsMoviesService;
    private readonly ICNSTranslationsService cnsTranslationsService;
    private readonly IFFMpegService ffMpegService;
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWorkAsync;
    private readonly IVideoService videoService;

    public CNSDeployerService(IOrderItemService orderItemService,
                ICNSCapMoviesService cnsCapMoviesService,
                ICNSTranslationsService cnsTranslationsService,
                IFFMpegService ffMpegService,
                IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWorkAsync,
                IVideoService videoService)
    {
        this.orderItemService = orderItemService;
        this.cnsMoviesService = cnsCapMoviesService;
        this.cnsTranslationsService = cnsTranslationsService;
        this.ffMpegService = ffMpegService;
        this.unitOfWorkAsync = unitOfWorkAsync;
        this.videoService = videoService;
    }

    public void Deploy(IEnumerable<Guid> orderItemIds)
    {
        try
        {
            InnerDeploy(orderItemIds);
        }
        catch
        {
            unitOfWorkAsync.Dispose();
        }

    }

    private void InnerDeploy(IEnumerable<Guid> orderItemIds)
    {
        var orderItems = orderItemService.Queryable()
          .Where(orderItem => orderItemIds.Any(itemId => orderItem.Id == itemId)
              && orderItem.IsInProcessQueue == false
              && !orderItem.TranslationId.HasValue)
          .ToList();

        if (orderItems.Count == 0)
        {
            unitOfWorkAsync.Dispose();
            throw new ArgumentNullException("No valid orders was provided");
        }

        foreach ( var orderItem in orderItems)
         {
            orderItem.IsInProcessQueue = true;
            orderItemService.Update(orderItem);
        }

         unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChanges();

        var translationId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var movieId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var connectedMoviePath = cnsMoviesService.GetMoviePath(movieId);
        var videosUrlList = orderItems
            .Select(orderItem => orderItem.VideosTable.VideoUrl)
            .ToList();

        //Don't await on this task since we want concat to continue after request is returned
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await ffMpegService.ConcatVideos(videosUrlList, connectedMoviePath);
                VideoUtils.CreateVideoImageAndReturnPath(connectedMoviePath);

                var videosTotalDuration = videoService.GetVideosTotalDuration(orderItemIds);
                var durationInSeconds = Convert.ToInt32((int)(videosTotalDuration / 1000));
                await cnsMoviesService.CreateMovieRecordAsync(movieId, durationInSeconds);
                await cnsTranslationsService.CreateTranslationRecordAsync(movieId, translationId, language: 1);

                var index = 0;
                foreach (var orderItem in orderItems)
                {
                    orderItem.TranslationId = translationId;
                    orderItem.TranslationIndex = index++;
                    orderItem.IsInProcessQueue = false;
                    orderItemService.Update(orderItem);
                }

                await unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                //TODO: Handle error
            }
            finally
            {
                //Dispose db context
                unitOfWorkAsync.Dispose();
            }

        });
    }


}
```