# Disposing dependencies in ASP.NET application with Hangfire

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container, hangfire, hangfire-unity

Typically in my ASP.NET MVC  application that uses `Unity` as dependency framework i use `PerRequestLifetimeManager` which disposes all the dependencies when HTTP request completes.

Now i configured Hangfire into ASP.NET application. Hangfire schedules a background job that has dependency on `DBContext`.  Something like below

*(The IGenericRepository use DBContext but for brevity purpose that code is not shown here)*

```
public interface IMyService:IDisposable
{
    void DoWork();
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private bool _disposed = false;

    protected readonly IGenericRepository _repository = null;        

    public MyService(IGenericRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));            
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {

    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_repository != null)
            {
                _repository.Dispose();
            }
            // Free any other managed objects here.                    
        }

        // Free any unmanaged objects here.
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

}

and then on application startup i register a recurring job like below

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IMyService>(x => x.DoWork(), Cron.Hourly());
```

I understand that i cannot use `PerRequestLifetimeManager` because there wont be HttpContext available when Hangfire schedules a background job.
But i wanted to know what lifetime manager i should be using here to register `IGenericRepository` and `IMyService` so that Dispose method will get invoked implicitly as soon as the job is done.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [Resolving type with PerRequestLifetimeManager without HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593487/resolving-type-with-perrequestlifetimemanager-without-http-request)

I have to use `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`

and then 
Change this...

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
    new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

to this...

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
    new Unity.WebApi.UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(container);
```